# How do I turn the heat down in my house?

Tags: heating

I just moved into this house. It still has the radiator unit but it's too hot. How do I turn the heat down? I turned the thermostat off, but it's still hot: does that mean I need a new thermostat?

Answer (score 0):

With a hot water system you can have more than one zone. Check if you have other thermostats in the house.

Comment: If that is the correct thermostat, I think a stuck control valve is more likely than a bad thermostat. Could be either, or broken wiring, or something else depending on the specifics of your system.